# programming settings of a software using java

Tags: java

I'm building a restaurant system, and I want to give adminstrator a privilege to change and save the settings so that when other users log in, will find new settings.

Comment: Is the program and information going to be on one machine? Will the different users be logging in to the machine with different logins, or will the software be running under one login, and you then control logins through a different system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has a dedicated [preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html), which is more powerful than using Properties files - that should be exactly what you want. It offers "System" preferences and "User" preferences - presumably the admin would be allowed to change "System" preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the java properties api to save any settings as Key-Value pairs.

A tutorial is here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

This can save your properties as .properties files as well as XML files

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory to the disk and store files which are looking like

```
user=Ben
font=arial
...
```

These file you can read with a java.util.Properties object.

```
Properties p;
p.load(inStream);
```

The properties you can add to the system properties and use it in every location of your code by calling

```
System.setProperty(font, arial);

System.getProperty(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it :
- Serialization
- Preferences API
- Using text files (XML, properties file, ini like files, etc.)
- Databases